# .NET - How can I change the Date format by creating a new Culture in .NET?

Tags: .net, globalization

My code is like this:

```
CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder cib = new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder("eh-sim", CultureAndRegionModifiers.None);
cib.LoadDataFromCultureInfo(new CultureInfo("en-us"));
cib.LoadDataFromRegionInfo(new RegionInfo("US"));
cib.CultureEnglishName = "Versão de teste";
cib.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = "   ";

cib.Register();
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("eh-sim");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
Console.WriteLine("EnglishName:. . . . . . . . . . {0}", ci.EnglishName);
Console.WriteLine(123.456.ToString("C"));
Console.ReadKey();
```

I want to the date format be for example:
10//12//10

Comment: And what is the problem you are having with doing that? What are the exact issues you have experienced?

Comment: There is no problem, it's just to study for certification.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the [`cib.GregorianDateTimeFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureandregioninfobuilder.gregoriandatetimeformat.aspx) to a suitable [`DateTimeFormatInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx) that has the `DateSeparator` you want (`//`).

Comment: yes, I did it, thank you.
cib.GregorianDateTimeFormat = new DateTimeFormatInfo(){DateSeparator = "//"};